# Nested structures in JCo for SAP?

Tags: nested, abap, saprfc, jco

I currently maintain rfc function modules to be called via Java Connector for SAP. My current module returns a table of documents, where each line has some data and another table of items. 
When introspecting this module via JCo 3.0, it does only show the top layer table, but not the one inside:

```
     POSITIONS () (com.sap.conn.jco.JCoTable) 
     introspection errror
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to access row values in a table
     which does not have any rows yet
```

The inner table is defined. For performance purposes, I enabled the module to use basXML. 
How can I enable JCo to work with nested structures? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 3):

In general this works. JCo is capable of dealing with nested structures and tables.

In this case your nested JCoTable simply seems to be empty, i.e. it has no rows.
On an empty table you cannot call any getter- or setter-method for a single field.

Simply check with `JCoTable.isEmpty()` or with `JCoTable.getNumRows()>0` before using any getter-method. And make sure to append at least one row with `JCoTable.appendRow()` before using any setter-method on a JCoTable object.

Comment: I tried adding one initial line on SAP side for this table, so it should always have at least one line, empty or not. But what I did on JCo was not receiving any data, I just introspected the function module I want to call - there should be no data right now, not in the outer and not in the inner table.
And still with this initial line, it broke with the same error. :|

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough: Your Java code has a bug!
If you would code as said in my answer you won't get a java.lang.IllegalStateException with this error message.
If your JCoTable is empty although it should not be empty, this is another issue which I cannot help with the little given info.